# Meaning of "Deep Winter "

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives, figurative-language

I have a question about the meaning of "*deep*" [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=u7guk073i_gC&pg=PP5&dq=%22deep+winter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f4-MVcbvH5TgoATy4aeADQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22deep%20winter%22&f=false):

> We are about to be confronted with the dangers of ***deep winter***.

What does "*deep*" refer to?  Does it mean the later part of winter?

Answer (score 5):

It means **the most intense part**. In some cases (depending on the climate), that could be the later part of winter.